# Render multiple files in POV-Ray (Windows)

Tags: file, render, scene, povray

I know this has been asked before, but none of the answers really helped me. So my problem is this: I have a bunch of .pov files named, XXXXX000001...., and I want to render them, but the queue thing inside of POV-Ray only lets you render 500 at a time. So, is there a way to render them all automatically? I know the answer is to write a script of some kind, but I don't know a lot about it so if you could give me a step by step instructions I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a POV-Ray .ini file **SimpleAnimation.ini** using notepad, and in that file specify the number of .pov files as [**Initial_Frame**/**Final_Frame**](http://www.povray.org/documentation/view/3.6.0/113/). This .ini file is the file you Open and Run to render all the frames. You can also use **Subset_Start_Frame**/**Subset_End_Frame** with duplicate .ini files when rendering subsets over multiple machines:

```
Input_File_Name="SimpleAnimation.pov"
Width=800
Height=600
Antialias=On
Antialias_Threshold=0.05
Output_File_Type=N

Initial_Frame=1
Final_Frame=124

# Change these values to render a subset of the frames #
Subset_Start_Frame=1
Subset_End_Frame=124
```

Your **SimpleAnimation.pov** file will then be loaded once per frame and in that .pov file you just load the relevant frame file you want using the POV-Ray variable [**frame_number**](http://www.povray.org/documentation/view/3.6.1/228/#s02_02_01_03_06_i5):

```
#if(frame_number=1)
#include "SimpleAnimation000001.pov"
#end
#if(frame_number=2)
#include "SimpleAnimation000002.pov"
#end
#if(frame_number=3)
#include "SimpleAnimation000003.pov"
#end
```

The rendered images will be generated with names according to the **Input_File_Name** in the **SimpleAnimation.ini** file with leading zeros according to the number of digits in **Final_Frame**, e.g. for 124 frames you get:

```
SimpleAnimation001.png
SimpleAnimation002.png
...
SimpleAnimation124.png
```

Answer (score 0):

An addition to the previous answer, **SimpleAnimation.pov** file can be just a one line:

> #include concat("FolderPath/SimpleAnimation.", str(frame_number, -6, 0), ".pov")